# Flash - Invisible stage background?

Tags: flash

Is there a cross-browser solution to making a flash players background invisible?

I have a swf movie that I want to sit on a faintly stripped background.  I could place the same background in the Flash movie and sit it with CSS - using hacks for ie to make the backgrounds match up, but wondered whether there was a simple way of turning the background off?

Thanks for your help!

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the wmode parameter to 'transparent' when you're creating the flash object.

Simple as that!

Comment: cool, cheers - is that cross browser - or does ie6 screw things up?

Comment: Yep, cross browser. I'd recommend using SwfObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) to embed your swf easily cross browser and it works fine for me in IE6. But you never know with IE6 ;)